# Apache POI evaluate formula

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have some formulas in cells of my sheet, and I want to evaluate them after I insert some values. Ex :

My formula is `=SUM(B1,B2)`

Before values insertion `B1` value was `1`, and `B2` value was `3`, and the formula result is `4`

After insertion of values now B1 has value `5`, and B2 has value `2` but the formula still produces `4`, how can I evaluate/trigger this to be calculated?

Naturally after I hit the return button on the formula cell the new value `7` is calculated, is there a way to trigger this without manual interaction?

I'm using excel 2007 so `XSSFWorkbook`

**EDIT/UPDATE :**

I've used Gabors solution before he posted it but I'm using it as a reference, here is what happens :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.<init>(Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/EvaluationWorkbook;Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/IStabilityClassifier;Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/record/formula/udf/UDFFinder;)V
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.<init>(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:64)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.<init>(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:51)
...............
...............
```

Here is a part of the relevant code :

```
public XSSFFormulaEvaluator getEvaluator(){
        if(evaluator == null){
            evaluator = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(wb);
        }
        return evaluator;
    }
```

actually invoking evaluator :

```
//where index is int, and mycell is int
row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(index);
cell = row.createCell(mycell);
getEvaluator().evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
```

I'm looking for someone used this and was successful, not those who google solution without really trying it, I've been googling a lot to say at least.

Per Gagravar suggestion I do have 2 POIs on my classpath :

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I though I need 3.7 version for XSSF workbooks etc.

**SOLUTION :**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.8-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: The NoSuchMethodError indicates to me that you have two copies of the POI jar on your classpath. Ensure you only have the one then it should work fine

Comment: That's your problem. Your POI versions need to match. You'll want 3.8-beta1 (or even better 3.8-beta2) for both the main POI jar, and the poi-ooxml one. You can't mix and match POI jars between versions!

Comment: @Gagravarr please provide some kind of answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To promote a comment to an answer...

You firstly need to ensure you're using the same version of POI for the main jar, and the OOXML part. Your maven snippet was showing 3.7 for one, and 3.8 beta 1 for the other. You need to make sure they're both the same. (You might even want to use 3.8-beta2 which is just out).

Then, use either:

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
```

or:

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
```

See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html for more details

Comment: Greetings from 2017 :) Thanks for the answer! This is exactly what I was looking for :) FYI `evaluateFormulaCell` is deprecated in poi 3.17 and `formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);` should be used instead.

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev I think you're mistaken - [evaluateFormulaCell](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateFormulaCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-) remains un-deprecated! `evaluateInCell` does something different, it replaces the formula with the result of the eval

Comment: but evaluateInCell() is not working for more than 255 columns? what is the reason for this.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps [XSSFFormulaEvaluator](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFormulaEvaluator.html)`.evaluateAllFormulaCells(XSSFWorkbook wb)` ?

(or more specifically: `evaluateFormulaCell(Cell cell)`.)

If it doesn't work: what version of POI are you using? Formulas in XSSF are supported from v3.5.

Also, try to use [XSSFCreationHelper](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCreationHelper.html) to instantiate your Formula Evaluator as suggested by the [POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html).

Comment: please don't tell me just googled that? Have you actually used this successfully ?

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html - what Gabor suggested should work just fine.

Comment: @Gagravarr I already did, have you ever used this successfully ?

Comment: Yes, works just fine for me. Also works just fine for a few hundred unit tests within POI too...

Answer (score 0):

if you using HSSF try :

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
 public static void triggerFormula(HSSFWorkbook workbook){      

                FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                int lastRowNo=sheet.getLastRowNum();        

                for(int rownum=0;rownum<=lastRowNo;rownum++){
                Row row;
                 if (sheet.getRow(rownum)!=null){
                         row= sheet.getRow(rownum);

                      int lastCellNo=row.getLastCellNum();

                          for(int cellnum=0;cellnum<lastCellNo;cellnum++){  
                                  Cell cell;
                                  if(row.getCell(cellnum)!=null){
                                     cell = row.getCell(cellnum);   
                                    if(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA==cell.getCellType()){
                                    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
                                }
                            }
                         }
                 }
                }


            }
```