# Apache POI does not apply the formula

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I want to apply some formulas to some cells, here the code:

```
c2.setCellValue ("Total:");

c3.setCellFormula("SUM(D4:D6)");
c4.setCellFormula("SUM(E4:E6)");
c5.setCellFormula("SUM(#REF!)");
```

But as you see in the picture the formulas does not apply to the last cell:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache POI evaluate formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716664/apache-poi-evaluate-formula)

Comment: Why do you want to give the formula SUM(#REF!) to cell c5? The formula is not valid (or at least not useful for anything).

Comment: The error value `#REF!` is the one and only correct result of `=SUM(#REF!)`. What else are you expecting as the result?