# Formula not evaluating through Java + Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have one excel sheet which I am reading through Apache POI, In which one cell contains the following formula.

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(A3:T3<>"sample"),COLUMN(A3:T3)),9999)`

I have tried everything which is available on the internet. Also, do the following things.

`FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();`

Every time it returns me a 9999 value. Instead of actual value which is 11.

Comment: You really tried everything which is available on the Internet? Like really everything? Sorry but your post is missing the implementation details (your code) to see what your problem is. So I suggest that you'll try some examples of: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html

Comment: Does the formula work fine if you open the excel file directly?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716664/apache-poi-evaluate-formula

Comment: I have tried all that options.

Answer (score 3):

The formula

```
LOOKUP(2,1/(A3:T3<>"sample"),COLUMN(A3:T3))
```

violates the rules of the [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb). It uses the vector form with lookup_vector `1/(A3:T3<>"sample")` which produces a vector having `#DIV/0!` if `A3:T3<>"sample"` is false, else `1`. So lookup_vector is something like `{#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,1,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,...}`

But the rules clearly state:

> Important: The values in **lookup_vector** must be placed in ascending
>   order: ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE; otherwise,
>   **LOOKUP** might not return the correct value. Uppercase and lowercase text are equivalent.

There is nothing said about error values. And even if error values would be possible here, what is then the "ascending order" of those?

It is one thing that `Excel` itself produces results even for that wrong formula. But you cannot expect that other software also will produce results for formulas which violates  the given rules.