# Problem with formula when clone from a workbook to another workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

The formula didn't work at new workbook when I try to clone an old workbook to new workbook. it just displayed value of 0. It might only work when I double-click on it and enter :(

```
package com.poi.xssf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            FileInputStream fisOld = null;
            FileInputStream fisNew = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            //initialize vars
            File fileOld = new File("test/copied.xlsx");
            File fileNew = new File("test/test.xlsx");
            fisOld = new FileInputStream(fileOld); // input: access A
            //fisNew = new FileInputStream(fileNew); 
            XSSFWorkbook oldworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fisOld);
            XSSFWorkbook newworkbook = oldworkbook;
            XSSFSheet spreadsheet =  newworkbook.getSheet("DeXuat");
            Row row = spreadsheet.getRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
            cell.setCellFormula("B1-C1");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileNew);
            newworkbook.write(fos);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to evaluate formulas before saving the workbook

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache POI evaluate formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716664/apache-poi-evaluate-formula)

Comment: Please read https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation